# Repeated Rcpp NumericVector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a vector `x` from which I want to create a vector `y` consisting of multiple copies of `x`. So, if `x` is `{1, 2, 3}` and the number of repetitions `n` is 3, `y` would be `{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}`. `x` must either be a `std::vector<double>` or an `Rcpp::NumericVector`. `y` must be an `Rcpp::NumericVector`. I use C++20.

Of course, I could simply iterate over the elements like:

```
const int x_size = x.size();
Rcpp::NumericVector y (x_size * n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  const int s = x_size * i;
  for(int j = 0; j < x_size; ++j) {
    y[s + j] = x[j];
  }
}
```

But I guess there is a better solution than such a nested loop.

Instead of creating `y`, I also considered dynamically resizing `x` to size `x.size() * n` and inserting multiple copies of itself, but did not find out how to do this with an `Rcpp::NumericVector`.

So, how do I create `y` from `x` and `n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This already exists as Rcpp sugar function `rep(x, n)` modeled after the equivalent base R function.

##### Code

```
#include <Rcpp/Rcpp>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector myrep(Rcpp::NumericVector x, int n) {
    return Rcpp::rep(x, n);
}

/*** R
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
n <- 3
myrep(x, n)
*/
```

##### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

> n <- 3

> myrep(x, n)
 [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
>
```

##### Discussion

You still may want to entertain writing such a function yourself. You have accessor `size()` and `length()` for the incoming vector, you have `n` and the rest are just two careful loops (in the simplest approach).

Comment: Thanks. I benchmarked it and the loops are indeed faster than `Rcpp::rep`.

Comment: I doubt that (for any meaningful sizes and repetitions) but maybe a reproducible benchmark comparing R's own `rep()` (which is likely 'fast enough', `Rcpp::rep()` and your solution.  Sometimes we 'win' by doing fewer argument checks and alike, on non-trivial payloads and comparisons that washes out.